# How to print two adjacent lines in a loop while keeping both of them in single lines in c++

Tags: c++

I have two strings in a for loop. I want to print them both adjacent to each other, while keeping them both in single lines. I used "\r" for both of them, but without an endl the 2nd string prints while the 1st doesn't.

```
cout << "\r" << row;
track[pos] = '^';
cout << "\r" << track;
```

It's in a for loop, so if I type an endl after the first cout, then the 1st string moves on to a new line after every iteration. Is there a way to keep both strings in their own lines?

Answer (score 1):

Both strings are printed, but the `'\r'` character is the *carriage **return*** character, which puts the cursor on the first position of the line. That means the second output will *overwrite* the first output.

Simply print a space between the two strings and it should work:

```
cout << "\r" << row;
track[pos] = '^';
cout << ' ' << track;
//      ^^^
// Print a single space
```

If the goal is to print the output in two columns and then print a newline, you should do that instead:

```
cout << row;
track[pos] = '^';
cout << ' ' << track << '\n';
```

Comment: Yeah I probably asked the question incorrectly.. I meant that the "track" string needs to be in a 2nd line below the "row" string. While they are both staying in their lines, as in, without moving into a new one after the loop

Comment: @PleaseDontHurtMe • that kind of positioning is outside the scope of the core C++ language and its C++ standard library.  You'll need to use something like NCurses (for a console app), or OS console APIs, or some sort of GUI framework.  Depending on your platform (if it supports ANSI X3.64), you may be able to fudge it by using ANSI X3.64 control sequences.